# Distinct behavior for Word JS-api for local install and browser version on #document.saved on just opened document

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I built an extension that checks periodically if document has been changed. This happens using an interval with a function that uses Word JS Api.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=word-js-preview#saved):

> Indicates whether the changes in the document have been saved. **A value of true indicates that the document hasn't changed since it was saved**.

*Emphasis mine*.

A sample code would be:

```
setInterval(function () { isSaved(); }, 1000 );
```

```
export const isSaved  = async () => {
  return Word.run(async context => {
    const thisDocument = context.document;
    context.load(thisDocument, 'saved');

    await context.sync();

    // edited bellow code for reprodutibility
    console.log(thisDocument.saved);
  });
}
```

When an existing document and doing nothing with it, we can expect the value to be `true`, as no changes happened. That is exactly what happens when opening it on Word Online. However, on my local Word application, it returns `false`.

How to make it behave the same? And why would it return `false` if document has not been edited?

Answer (score 2):

One frequent reason for a document to be marked as "dirty" after being opened, but not edited, is the update of connections to outside sources (a linked Excel table or chart, for example) and field codes.

If, for example, the document has a `Page`field in the footer, that will be updated when the document is opened. Even if the value does not change, this is still regarded by the Word UI as a change to the document. Thus, its `saved` property is set to `false`.

The reason this isn't seen in Word On-line is because that version does not support the use (inserting, editing or updating) of field codes. Word On-line does not remove field codes present in the document and *may* display the calculated field code result at the time the document was last saved. But since Word On-line does not update field codes the `saved` property will be `true`in that environment when it is not in Word for Windows or for the Mac.

The only way the value could be the same for all environments would be to remove any content that's updated when Word opens a document. Field codes can be "locked", but not using the Office JS APIs, which do not support field codes (ironically, because they're not available in Word On-line).

Comment: Thanks, Cindy. Very interesting catch. That could be a reason for some files. 

However, I opened a new blank document, wrote "test" and saved it as "test.docx". Then I closed Word and opened that same document again. It's still showing up as changed, but has no connections to outside sources. 

Feels like the problem goes deeper than that.

Comment: @IgorGalvão It can also have something to do with the template from which the document was created (and would still be linked). For example, if the document were set to automatically update styles, or if the template has any "auto" macros going. It could also be because of any kind of add-in running in the Word environment...